# Optimizing a SQL query on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query on SQL Server that needs to be optimized.
It takes almost 16 minutes to run it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DeptNo,
                BrandDesc,
                MfgDesc,
                CountOfActiveSKUs =
                    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                FROM dbo.SKU k
                               WHERE k.Status = 'A'
                                 AND k.BrandDesc = s.BrandDesc
                                 AND k.MfgDesc = s.MfgDesc
                                 AND k.DeptNo = s.DeptNo),
                             0)
           FROM dbo.SKU s
       ORDER BY BrandDesc
```

I came up with the following, but it doesn't seems it grabs records that have CountOfActiveSKUs = 0.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DeptNo,
                BrandDesc,
                MfgDesc,
                CountOfActiveSKUs = COALESCE(Count(*), 0)
           FROM dbo.SKU
          WHERE Status = 'A'
       GROUP BY BrandDesc, MfgDesc, DeptNo
       ORDER BY BrandDesc
```

Any help is appreciated, 
Thank you!

Comment: For the record, it is almost always a poor choice to use a correlated sub-query in a select. Please stop using this technique altogether. because it is a performance killer and it is virtually never necessary.

Comment: @HLGEM Agree, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT DeptNo, BrandDesc, MfgDesc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY BrandDesc, MfgDesc, DeptNo) as CountOfActiveSKUs
FROM dbo.SKU s
ORDER BY BrandDesc;
```

I would leave the `SELECT DISTINCT` out, unless it is absolutely necessary.  If it is necessary, then use an explicit `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DeptNo, BrandDesc, MfgDesc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountOfActiveSKUs
FROM dbo.SKU s
GROUP BY DeptNo, BrandDesc, MfgDesc
ORDER BY BrandDesc;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! The first query you wrote has duplicate records on the result, but the second query works great!

Comment: @Springray . . . The explicit `GROUP BY` is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Don't filter the status, count the SKUs with status='A' using a conditional SUM.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DeptNo,
                BrandDesc,
                MfgDesc,
                SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountOfActiveSKUs
           FROM dbo.SKU
       GROUP BY BrandDesc, MfgDesc, DeptNo
       ORDER BY BrandDesc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT s.DeptNo, s.BrandDesc, s.MfgDesc, count(k.Status) as CountOfActiveSKUs
FROM  dbo.SKU s LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.SKU k ON 
k.Status = 'A' AND k.BrandDesc = s.BrandDesc
AND k.MfgDesc = s.MfgDesc AND k.DeptNo = s.DeptNo
GROUP BY s.DeptNo, s.BrandDesc, s.MfgDesc
ORDER BY BrandDesc
```